angular 17 SSR lazyloading modules not working
after update my angular app from version 10 to version 17, i add SSR using @nguniversal/express-engine and express  to this project and it work in build and run ssr on port 4000 , but when i navigate to routes all pages ssr not working . my angular app is using lazyloading module and i create log in server.ts only log is c created for  / route and in other route not working . my app not have any error in server ts log, when i check viewSource the content is not showing as html in viewsource , how to fix it ?
this is my serverRouting :
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {routes} from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppServerRoutingModule {

}


and
route in appRouting :
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {ErrorNotFoundComponent} from './error-pages/error-not-found/error-not-found.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./layouts/layout.module').then((m) => m.LayoutModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/landing/landing.module').then((m) => m.LandingModule)
  },
  {path: '404', component: ErrorNotFoundComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      scrollOffset: [0, 150]
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

and my server.ts file is :
import 'zone.js/node';
import { join } from 'path';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import express from 'express';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/JustyBookWebApp/browser');
  const indexHtml = join(distFolder, 'index.html');

  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Rendering request for URL:', req.url);

    res.render(indexHtml, { req }, (err, html) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Rendering request Error:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
      } else {
        res.send(html);
      }
    });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();

and my TransferHttpResponseInterceptor:
import {isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {makeStateKey, TransferState} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {RequestKeyExtractorService} from './request-key-extractor.service';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

const STATE_KEY_PREFIX = 'http_requests:';

@Injectable()
export class TransferHttpResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private transferState: TransferState,
    private requestKeyExtractor: RequestKeyExtractorService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object // Change to Object for PLATFORM_ID
  ) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Interceptor - Platform:', this.platformId);
    console.log('Interceptor - Request Method:', req.method);
    console.log('Interceptor - Request URL:', req.url);
    // Nothing to do with non-GET requests
    if (req.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const key = makeStateKey<HttpResponse<object>>(STATE_KEY_PREFIX + this.requestKeyExtractor.getKey(req));
    console.log(`key is ${key}`);
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      console.log(`is browser platform`);
      // Try reusing transferred response from server
      const cachedResponse = this.transferState.get(key, null);
      if (cachedResponse) {
        this.transferState.remove(key); // using transferred state should be used for the very first time
        return of(new HttpResponse({
          body: cachedResponse.body,
          status: 200,
          statusText: 'OK (from server)',
        }));
      }
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      console.log(`is server platform`);
      console.log(`key is ${key}`);
      // Try saving response to be transferred to browser
      return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event => {

        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status === 200) {
          // Update the cache.
          const response = {
            body: event.body
          };

          this.transferState.set(key, response);
        }
      }));
    }

    // Add a fallback return statement to ensure all code paths return a value
    return next.handle(req); // Handles the case where the platform isn't recognized
  }
}


and my main.server.ts is :
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import {environment} from '@env/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export {AppServerModule} from './app/app.server.module';


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

when i navigate to my app pages , ssr not working , it seems lazyloading modules not working is angular ssr , or it need a config !

To fix SSR with lazy-loaded routes in Angular, you need to make sure:

Correct module paths in appRouting.
Add provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP) in server.ts.
Handle lazy-loaded routes explicitly in server.ts.
Ensure initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' is set in both routing modules.
Check TransferHttpResponseInterceptor for proper state transfer.

i suggest these two options :
1- Add provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP) in server.ts to handle lazy-loaded routes properly.
2- Ensure initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' is in both AppRoutingModule and AppServerRoutingModule to allow Angular SSR to load lazy routes.

my angular version is 17, my nguniversal/express-engine  is version 16.2. (latest) , i add nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader 8.2.6 and in server.ts file i added this :   server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({     bootstrap: AppServerModule,     providers: [provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)]   })); but it have error : Argument type {bootstrap: AppServerModule, providers: (ValueProvider | ExistingProvider | StaticClassProvider | ConstructorProvider | FactoryProvider | any[])[]} is not assignable to parameter type Readonly

Those steps sound great.  Do you know if any resources that talk more about them in depth?  Like what is LAZY_MODULE_MAP and where am I putting that in the server.ts?  Same with the other steps.
